# How to create a common shadow for multiple strokes in a single canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to draw multiple strokes on a canvas and I'd like them to have a common shadow. Currently the cast shadows on one another which is not what I want.

### Ideal result

[image: ideal result]

### What I've tried

- Creating shadow using `ctx.shadowColor` [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zkm7h2cn/)
- Creating shadow using `ctx.filter` [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u70Lx1sb/)
- Creating shadow using css `box-shadow` on the canvas -- draws shadow on the whole box
- Creating shadow using css `filter` on the canvas -- draws shadow on the whole box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Path2D` and add all your segments to one path, then do the stroke to that path.

Here is your jsfiddle using ctx.filter with my recommendation.

```js
const segments = [
 [{x: 10, y: 50}, {x: 50, y: 50}],
 [{x: 50, y: 10}, {x: 50, y: 50}],
 [{x: 90, y: 50}, {x: 50, y: 50}],
 [{x: 50, y: 90}, {x: 50, y: 50}],
]

let path = new Path2D()
segments.forEach(segment => {  
  path.moveTo(segment[0].x, segment[0].y)
  path.lineTo(segment[1].x, segment[1].y)  
})

const ctx = document.getElementById('my-canvas').getContext('2d')
ctx.lineWidth = 5
ctx.filter = 'drop-shadow(-3px -3px 3px #f00)';
ctx.strokeStyle = 'black'
ctx.stroke(path)
```

```html
<canvas width="100" height="100" id="my-canvas" style="background: #00ff00"/>
```

You can read more about `Path2D` here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D/Path2D

Comment: From the description I assume they want all strokes to be independent, i.e eiter different stroke colors or lineWidth. Otherwise they wouldn't even need a Path2D, the inner path of the context is largely enough.

Comment: Also beware that Safari still doesn't support ctx.filter...

Comment: This works exactly as I expected. Although in my tests in chrome, using ctx.filter seems to have a heavy performance penalty.
I ended up drawing the same strokes twice in the same canvas, once with ctx.shadowBlur, and another time without shadow on top of it, and it's about 10x faster in my tests. The difference is noticeable visually, and in chrome performance inspector you'll see 100ms GPU blocks in case of using ctx.filter as oppose to <10ms blocks for ctx.shadowBlur.

Answer (score 0):

If you need each stroke to be independent (i.e so that they have each their own strokeStyle or lineWidth), you will need to use a second detached canvas:

- on this detached canvas you draw all your strokes without shadow
- you `drawImage` that detached canvas on the visible one with the shadow:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const detached = canvas.cloneNode();
const detachedCtx = detached.getContext("2d");
const colors = ["green", "blue", "yellow", "orange", "aqua"];  

detachedCtx.lineWidth = 5;
for (let color of colors) {
  // draw on the detached canvas
  detachedCtx.beginPath();
  for (let i = 0; i<5; i++) {
    detachedCtx.lineTo(Math.random() * canvas.width, Math.random() * canvas.height);
  }
  detachedCtx.strokeStyle = color;
  detachedCtx.lineWidth = Math.random() * 8 + 2;
  detachedCtx.stroke();
}

// now draw all this with shadows on the visible canvas
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 3;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 3;
ctx.shadowBlur    = 3;
ctx.shadowColor   = "red";
ctx.drawImage(detached, 0, 0);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

But to produce the image you have all you need is to call `stroke()` only once after you did compose your full path:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "#0F0";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.shadowOffsetX = -3;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = -3;
ctx.shadowBlur    = 3;
ctx.shadowColor   = "red";
ctx.moveTo(10, 50);
ctx.lineTo(90, 50);
ctx.moveTo(50, 10);
ctx.lineTo(50, 90);
ctx.stroke(); // stroke only once, with the full path being traced
```

```html
<canvas width=100 height=100></canvas>
```